# Unit testing code with MvxTrace

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have this code:

```cs
    public async Task DeleteListAsync(Models.List list)
    {
        var userList = (await _userListRepository.GetAllAsync())
            .Where(ul => ul.ListId.Equals(list.Id, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (userList != null)
            await _userListRepository.DeleteAsync(userList);
        else
            MvxTrace.Error(string.Format("Unable to find UserList entry for List {0}.", list.Id));

        await _listRepository.DeleteAsync(list);
    }
```

The question I have is a s follows - how do I unit test this code with a call to MvxTrace which is part of MvvmCross framework.  I know that I can wrap a call into MvxTrace into my own interface base method and provide own implementation for unit test purposes but is there a better/different way to provide a mock implementation for MvxTrace without the effort of wrapping it?

Comment: check out the `IMvxTrace` interface. That is the abstraction that should allow the decoupled dependency.

Comment: I know that and as part of the application, i provide the implementation for the IMvxTrace file but what to do within a unit test?

Comment: Found this on a commit in the repo `[Obsolete("IMvxTrace is replaced by IMvxLogProvider and IMvxLog")]` on the `MvxTrace` class if it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mvx 5.x or greater you shouldn't use `MvxTrace` anymore and use `IMvxLog` instead, then you can inject it in the constructor and do the unit tests easier.

If not you have to create your own implementation of `IMvxTrace` and register it because as you can see [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.4.0/MvvmCross/Platform/Platform/Platform/MvxTrace.cs#L122) (*Mvx 4.4.0 implementation of MvxTrace*) `MvxTrace` resolves `IMvxTrace` that is what the static methods call at the end.

Create custom `MvxTrace`:

```
public class MyTestableMvxTrace : IMvxTrace
{
    // Implement the interface adding custom flags
    // or data so that you can use it in the assert
    ...
}
```

Register it in your test:

```
Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxTrace, MyTestableMvxTrace>();
```

HIH